# how to return some default value in oracle cursor when nothing is found

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following statement in one of the oracle SP:

```
OPEN CUR_NUM FOR 
   SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(num)) as num 
   FROM USER WHERE USER_ID = v_user_id;
```

When the above does not return anything the SP result just has no column name in it.  But I'd like the cursor to still have `num` column with some default value like `NOTHING` when no data is found.

Is this doable ?

Comment: In general this is bad practice.  It is usually better to handle the empty set than to use a magic value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to do that, you could use a `UNION` to select your dummy-row in case the `user_id` does not exist:

```
OPEN CUR_NUM FOR 
   SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(num)) AS num 
   FROM user WHERE USER_ID = v_user_id
 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'NOTHING' AS num
   FROM dual
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM user
     WHERE user_id = v_user_Id
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

two choices i think:

add NVL() around the value if there is a row being returned but the column is null,

otherwise

add a MIN or MAX function if possible - this can force a row to be returned

Answer (score 0):

If this code block is being used in a function, the following would work like a charm:

First, define your return variable

```
v_ret VARCHAR2(24);
```

Now, define cursor `CUR_NUM` as your select statement

```
CURSOR CUR_NUM IS
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(num)) as num 
   FROM USER WHERE USER_ID = v_user_id;

BEGIN
OPEN CUR_NUM;
FETCH CUR_NUM into v_ret;
CLOSE CUR_NUM;

RETURN nvl(v_ret,'NOTHING');
end;
```